# Best way to convert column nested to row nested

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

Suppose I have an array with nested "columns"

```
column_nested = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 4]]
```

How would I convert it into a "rowwise nested array"?

```
row_nested = [[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
```

My solution: `row_nested = collect(eachrow(hcat(column_nested...)))` seems a bit verbose and severely messes with types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using broadcasting and `zip`:

```
julia> row_nested = collect.(zip(column_nested...))
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 5]
 [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: When I try it with a lager dataset like `column_nested = repeat([[1,2]], 10000)` I get errors like: `Internal error: stack overflow in type inference of broadcasted(Function, Base.Iterators.Zip{NTuple{10000, Array{Int64, 1}}}).` `This might be caused by recursion over very long tuples or argument lists.`

Comment: @GKi It isn't the most efficient way to achieve this, as your answer and the others show, but it is readable. The other solutions in Bogumil's and your answer are options in this case. Of course, the best method is to originally place the data in a matrix and then the transpose operation will be more memory local and optimized for (and perhaps unnecessary with a logically permuted index instead of memory permuted index).

Answer (score 2):

If `column_nested` is long the approach proposed by Dan will be very slow. A more scalable alternative is:

```
julia> [getindex.(column_nested, i) for i in 1:maximum(length, column_nested)]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 5]
 [2, 3, 4]
```

Note that it assumes that each row uses 1-based indexing (for simplicity).

If you use SplitApplyCombine.jl package, you can just write:

```
julia> invert(column_nested)
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 5]
 [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Valid, but performance is not a factor. Great insight nevertheless

Comment: Using `minimum` instead of `maximum` is better (so `getindex` would always work)

Comment: if you use `minimum` you will silently get an error if inner vectors have unequal length. I would prefer to get an error in such case.

Comment: That's legitimate. Just for readability, I'm noting same check can be expressed as `allequal(length.(column_nested))`

Answer (score 2):

A way could be to use `stack` to get a `matrix` like `hcat(column_nested...)` followed, also like in the question, by `eachrow`.

```
eachrow(stack(column_nested))
#2-element RowSlices{Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int64, #1, Matrix{Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, true}}:
# [1, 2, 5]
# [2, 3, 4]

collect.(eachrow(stack(column_nested)))
#2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
# [1, 2, 5]
# [2, 3, 4]
```

Taking the structure of `invert` from `SplitApplyCombine.jl`:

```
function cc2r(x::AbstractArray{T}) where {T <: AbstractArray}
  s = size(x)
  f = first(x)
  k = keys(f)
  out = Array{Array{eltype(T),length(s)}}(undef, size(f))
  @inbounds for i in k
    out[i] = Array{eltype(T)}(undef, s)
  end
  @inbounds for i in keys(x)
    t = x[i]
    for j in k
      out[j][i] = t[j]
    end
  end
  out
end

cc2r(column_nested)
#2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
# [1, 2, 5]
# [2, 3, 4]
```

---

Benchmark

```
using BenchmarkTools, SplitApplyCombine
column_nested = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 4]]

@btime eachrow(stack(column_nested))
#  54.035 ns (2 allocations: 144 bytes)

@btime cc2r(column_nested)
#  64.210 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)

@btime invert(column_nested)
#  64.243 ns (3 allocations: 224 bytes)

@btime eachrow(hcat(column_nested...))
#  97.181 ns (3 allocations: 176 bytes)

@btime collect.(eachrow(stack(column_nested)))
#  323.996 ns (7 allocations: 432 bytes)

@btime collect.(eachrow(hcat(column_nested...)))
#  385.337 ns (8 allocations: 464 bytes)

@btime collect.(zip(column_nested...))
#  519.194 ns (8 allocations: 432 bytes)

@btime [getindex.(column_nested, i) for i in 1:maximum(length, column_nested)]
#  895.587 ns (11 allocations: 464 bytes)
```

Larger dataset

```
column_nested = [rand(0:9, 100) for i in 1:100]

@btime eachrow(stack(column_nested))
#  4.506 μs (3 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

@btime eachrow(hcat(column_nested...))
#  8.957 μs (7 allocations: 80.72 KiB)

@btime collect.(eachrow(stack(column_nested)))
#  10.530 μs (106 allocations: 166.64 KiB)

@btime cc2r(column_nested)
#  12.053 μs (101 allocations: 88.38 KiB)

@btime invert(column_nested)
#  12.784 μs (101 allocations: 88.38 KiB)

@btime collect.(eachrow(hcat(column_nested...)))
#  18.616 μs (110 allocations: 169.16 KiB)

@btime [getindex.(column_nested, i) for i in 1:maximum(length, column_nested)]
#  43.563 μs (305 allocations: 94.73 KiB)

@btime collect.(zip(column_nested...))
#  134.412 ms (1909344 allocations: 93.42 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TensorCast.jl` package has been created by Michael Abbott to make this kind of thing easy for everyone:

```
using TensorCast
@cast row_nested[i][j] := column_nested[j][i]  # := lazy;  |= eager
```